# Automatically generated reports using rMarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am trying to generate about 50 reports with the same template in rMarkdown. I do not want to change the name of the input file every time and I would like to choose different names for output files.

Is there any way how to automate this process?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Another option is to render your reports using the render() function of the rmarkdown package in a seperate R script.

report.Rmd looks like this:

````
---
output: pdf_document
---
# A table with data received from R script

```{r,results='asis'}
library("knitr")
kable(mydataset)
```
````

The R script looks like that:

```
library("rmarkdown")
for (i in 1:50){ 
 mydataset <- head(mtcars) 
 render( input="report.Rmd", output_file=paste0("reportNo_", i, ".pdf") )
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I forgot to mention that for every input (report.Rmd) I am using a different dataset. So, in this case I would need 50 Rmd files. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can pass datasets from the R script to your Rmd-file. See my edited answer. Now you only need to define the dataset in each loop.

Comment: Done. Thanks. Sorry, I am new here.