# How to print multiple pdfs with Rmarkdown

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

So, at the moment I have an Rmarkdown file that knits a reports as a pdf.

However, I want to use the split function on my data frame and then loop on the list of vectors resulting from the split, each item resulting a new pdf.

For example, I currently have:

````
```{r}

summary(df)

```
````

And I want something like:

````
```{r}

dfs2 = split(df, df$colunm1, drop = TRUE)

for (i in 1:length(dfs2)){

    summary(dfs2[[1]])

}

```
````

And each summary in the loop will be a new pdf. However, if I just click "Knit PDF" I will only get a PDF with several pages of summaries, instead of multiple pdf each with a summary.

Is it possible to do this?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you really need Rmarkdown to do this? Why don't you just use the 'pdf' function?

Comment: Would it be possible to write in the pdf and put more than one graph? I am trying to make a report in which after a graph I also put some comments and other things. I never used the pdf function, only markdown for things like this.

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28368150/automatically-generated-reports-using-rmarkdown/28376041#28376041) is what you need.